# css sprite transition in responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, sprite

I'm trying to create a social toolbar, using sprite images. When the mouse hover a "button", the transition take place.

I'm using the code found in the cmsms Simplex theme; here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/TtP7K/

CSS code:

```
ul.social {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

.social li {
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 6px
}

.social li a {
    display: block;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    text-indent: -999em
}

.social li.facebook a {background: transparent url('http://www.scott-knight.net/facebook-sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0}
.social li.facebook a:hover {background: transparent url('http://www.scott-knight.net/facebook-sprite.png') no-repeat 0 -48px}
```

html code:

```
<ul class="social">
    <li class="facebook"><a title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a></li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately this implementation is not responsive; i've tryed to implement some workarounds, but so far no luck. 
I'm asking help to find a responsive layout.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hummm... what do you mean by "responsive layout"?

Comment: portion of css code that doen not use pixel values, but use %.

Comment: sorry, did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/Vy4d9/

```
a.fb {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: transparent url(http://www.scott-knight.net/facebook-sprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: background-position 250ms;
}

a.fb:hover {
    background-position: 0 -1em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    a.fb {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    a.fb {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    a.fb {
        font-size: 44px;
    }
}
```